# Few questions about SSL

Tags: linux, php, ssl, https, openssl

I am trying to develop an sslchecker.com analog for testing purposes.

I would like to understand few moments:

1. In results we can see "Resolves to" and "hostname". Is "Resolves to" a domain name, for which certificate is signed?
2. What is "hostname" in this case? It is not a form's value, because I see "Doesn't match" all the time. What should to be there?
3. How I can to detect with PHP functions of openssl or with pure openssl in terminal this:

3.1 "Resolves to" (to what domain it al is signed)

3.2 "hostname" (based on what is it from 2 question)

3.3 "Vendor signed" (yes or no. Yes - if we have "Issued by" values?)

3.4 PHP openssl functions gives to me chains without last Root certificate, why? How I can to take Root Certificate?

3.5 How I can to connect to one of certificate in chain with ssl protocol? What domain I should to use and port, how I can to detect it, is it possible?

3.6 How I can check domain of chain's certificates and to be sure, that certificates in chain are valid for this domains?

Sorry, if questions are not correct because of my bad english or bad SSL understanding. Also, what I can to read about? May be you can to recommend some video or short article instead of wiki?

Comment: Ask only a single question, question lists are not welcomed on the site.

Comment: Hehh, also my English isn't the best :-) Sergey Yllaryonow :-) I did it without google translate, I can read cyrillic script! I tried to fix some of your sentences, but now I think it is around okay. Also my English is bad, but I think yours is not so bad. Although I think your English may sound not very well for native speakers, I think they will understand it and it is enough. Some things you should know: 1) on serverfault.com, you can ask only from 1. professional things ("for educational purposes" substring makes your question off-topic!)

Comment: 2. for systemadministration things (your question is about programming). 3. As I wrote before, you can't ask a list of questions. But you are allowed to ask multiple questions at once. Only what is important: they should be independently comprehensible. 4. It is much better if your question doesn't depend on external things (for example, nobody will check sslchecker.com only to understand your question). The solution for this: simply ask for the details of the ssl. 5. Your whole post doesn't belong to this SE site, rather to one of the sister sites of this (there are around 150 from them).

Comment: Fulfilling all of these rules results that asking a question may be harder as answering it. It is because the system tries to make the task of the answerers so easy as it can. [Here](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is the list of all SE sites. I think the php & ssl part belong to the https://stackoverflow.com . The deeper ssl details could be a good match on https://security.stackexchange.com , while the command line part may go to https://unix.stackexchange.com . Any other to https://superuser.com . There is also a https://ru.stackoverflow.com , it is on Russian. Good luck!

Comment: @peterh thanks for your help. How can I rise up your rating? What I need to vote\like in your profile?